# Soap UI to Exchange

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to connect SOAP UI to our Exchange server but i keep getting an error in SOAP UI of

```
Error loading [https://<<our exchange server>>/ews/Services.wsdl]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected element: STRING
```

I am using this as our endpoint which i have been reading that it is this and not the WSDL URL.

```
https://<<Our Exchange Server>>/ems/exchange.asmx
```

Anyone know what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a typo in your code or just your comment, but the EWSUrl should be https://mail.contoso.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx, not /ems/.

Comment: Yeah it was just in my comment. I end up getting the log in box on SoapUI asking for UN, PW and Domain but after inputting the credentials i get the error above. Is there something at the exchange level that would restrict this?

Comment: Can you provide more context? What version of Exchange are you running and is the SOAP UI a custom solution? You may want to download EWSEditor, http://ewseditor.codeplex.com/, so you can try your login info there and see if you can access your server that way. If EWSEditor works/can access your mailbox, then you know your problem is in your solution.